# Tensorflow repeat a tensor by numbers in another tensor, similar to numpy.repeat

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have two tensors `a` and `b` that have the same shape. I want to repeat elements of `a` exactly by number of times specified in `b`. How can I achieve that in Tensorflow?

In numpy I'd use `np.repeat`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.5,0.1,0.15,0.25])
b = np.array([100,50,200,10])
c = np.repeat(a, b)
```

How to do this in tensorflow?

A very (dirty and probably inefficient) workaround would be to unstack both into lists and use `tf.tile` on each element and then `concat` the results. I managed to make something like this work:

```
a = tf.constant([0.5,0.1,0.15,0.25])
b = tf.constant([3,1,5,2])
a_list = tf.unstack(a)
b_list = tf.unstack(b)
result = []
for i in range(len(a_list)):
    tmp = tf.tile([a_list[i]], [b_list[i]])
        result.append(tmp)
    final = tf.concat([*result], axis=0)
```

Result:

```
final.eval()
Out:
array([ 0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.5       ,  0.1       ,
        0.15000001,  0.15000001,  0.15000001,  0.25      ,  0.25      ], dtype=float32)
```

Isn't there any better way?

Comment: @Psidom That answer works when you want to repeat `a` for a constant number of times. What I want is to repeat elements of `a` based on value of elements in another tensor `b`.

Comment: You are right. I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

I think a slightly better solution can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/59ecde3ecfc83aeb8ec0682e4e39bf0a234bbef8/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/resample.py#L32), which uses `tf.while` (rather than a Python for loop) to achieve what you want. This solution specifically repeats elements in `tf.range` but I think you can change this to work for an arbitrary input tensor.

FWIW there is an [open issue on the TensorFlow github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8246) asking for just this implementation (which is where I found a link to the above code).